# Trying to display users information in a recyclerview - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My app is using Firebase. The user can register and login. In the main activity, there is a menu option called **All Users**. All I want for now is to display the registered users in a recyclerview. Of course this means that I will have to query the database using

```
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

If I put a breakpoint in this line, I can read the users. That's no problem.

[image]

Next, I use this [page](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) to implement the **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**

The full code is shown below.

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private RecyclerView mUserList;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.users_appBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Users");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mUserList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    mUserList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUserList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
            .setQuery(mUsersDatabase, Users.class)
            .build();


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, int i,Users users) {
            usersViewHolder.setName(users.getName());
        }
    };
    mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        }

    public void setName (String name){
        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.singleUserName);
        userNameView.setText(name);
    }
  }
}
```

However, users are not displayed. Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the page that you linked, you need to do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
adapter.stopListening();
}
```

You need to add `startListening()` to begin listening for data, and the `stopListening()` call removes the event listener and all data in the adapter.

Comment: I found another problem. I created 3 users but only the first is shown:(.

Comment: I know what the error is. My recycle's view row was covering the whole screen:):). Thus I thought there was a problem. Stupid me.