# NullPointerException at FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a problem with my app. I am trying to show all my user's list and their details (status, phone number), but I keep on getting the null pointer exception error on the onStart method. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_status);


...

    }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
            options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                            .setQuery(mUserDbase, Users.class)
                            .build();
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.activity_customer_status, parent, false);

                    return new UsersViewHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Users users) {
                    usersViewHolder.setName(users.getName());
                    usersViewHolder.setPhone(users.getPhone());
                    usersViewHolder.setStatus(users.getStatus());

                }

            };
            mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }

        // View Holder Class

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setName (String name){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }
        public void setPhone (String phone){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.phone_text);
            userNameView.setText(phone);
        }
        public void setStatus (String status){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            userNameView.setText(status);
        }

    }

}
```

I've followed this question: [Error in FirebaseListAdapter.startListening()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802581/error-in-firebaselistadapter-startlistening), which explains that the activity life cycle works as (onCreate>onStart>onResume), so assuming that (i'm a newb) I placed my on start code above my firebaseRecyclerAdapter. I've also followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305216/trying-to-display-users-information-in-a-recyclerview-firebase) as a guide but it didn't help me either. Please help

Comment: Move `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();`
 just above  `mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the pointer `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` before initializing it.

```
  firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapte(){...}; 
  firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
  mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: So with this solution, do I still need to add the onStart method?